# Nonlinear Matrix Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Is there any general method to solve a matrix equation which may have some following form: (with $X$ is what needed to find)($A,B,C,D,X$ are all $n \times n$ matrices)(and in my particular case, $n=3$)

- $AX+XB+XCX+D=0$
- $X^T+AX^{-1}B=0$
- $A+X^TBX=0$

If there is no general method, what are some kinds of equation considered classical and solvable.

Note: They are separate equations.

Thanks very much! These kinds of equations appear in my research in physics.

Comment: What are the dimensions of $A$,$B$, and $X$? If you're doing physics I assume these are complex matrices.

Comment: They are $n \times n$, of course. And yes, they are complex.

Comment: and in my particular case, $n=3$

Comment: Just checking, the second and third equations imply that $B^2=I$.  Is that correct?  If it is, then the second equation is redundant.

Comment: Equation 3 looks to me like nine quadratic equations in nine unknowns (the entries of X), and that would in general have $2^9=512$ solutions.  Feed them back into Equation 1, and there are 512 possible matrices $D$.  Sorry, I don't even know how to turn 9 quadratic equations into a degree-512 polynomial.

Comment: If $X$ is symmetric all equations  are of Riccatty algebaraic equations and there are standard method to solve them http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation. If $X$ is not symmetric may be you can convert them somehow to the form when $X$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have 3 equations and 5 unknowns. With algebraic manipulations (by substituting for $A$ and then for $B$) you can get it to the form
$$-X^TX + I + XC + D = 0.$$

This way you're left with one equation and three unknowns. I don't think you can take it much further. The point is that you cannot solve for $X$ uniquely.

Comment: As I understand he has only one equation from the above with known $A,B,C$.

Comment: Yes. They are separate equations I encourter :).